# Recommendations for Ajax file upload control in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

Can anyone recommend a (preferably free) Ajax file upload control for ASP.NET MVC?

I don't need support for multiple file uploads, but I would like progress bar/percentage complete information. Ideally, it would be easy to get started with and use and be open source.

Please only recommend actual products you have used.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**[SlickUpload](http://krystalware.com/slickupload) isn't free but is by far the best package I have ever used.**

Full support for MVC and uploading to action methods, it uses HTML5 where possible and is fully cross-browser compatible. Progress bars and async uploads come out of the box too.

Answer (score 1):

I've used valums [file-uploader](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader) in different projects and I can't complain about it. If you want to see some code you can check another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272619/how-do-i-perform-a-ajax-jquery-upload-of-an-image-in-asp-net-mvc/5273352#5273352) of mine.