# How to upload a file without reloading the whole page in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

I have been working with MVC for the past few days.

I have a problem in one of my pages, i.e I have a page where q user enters the required details and uploads a file. I have two buttons named Upload for Uploading File and Create for creating new profile.

**My Problem**

My problem is I don't want to reload the whole page when user clicks on upload button. I was thinking of using an webmethod for fileupload.

I  don't know if what am I doing wrong here

Can any one correct me

This is my Webmethod in my controller named Create

**Controller**

```
   [WebMethod]
   public string  FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file, BugModel model)
   {             
       BugModel bug = null;
       if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
       {
           string path = "/Content/UploadedFiles/" + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
           string savedFileName = Path.Combine(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath ("~" +path));
           file.SaveAs(savedFileName);
           BugAttachment attachment = new BugAttachment();
           attachment.FileName = "~" + path.ToString();
           bug.ListFile.Add(attachment);
           model = bug;              
       }
       return "FileUploaded";          
   }
```

used a script to call the method

**Javascript**

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
      function UploadFile() {       
        $.ajax({
            type:"Post",
            url: "LogABug/FileUpload",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("File Uploaded")
            },
            error: function () {
                ErrorMessage("Try Again");
            }
        });
    }
 </script>
```

can any one tell me how can I do this ...if this is the wrong method correct me the right one with the ideas please

Comment: you can do this without using WebMethod also. see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5273352/1182982)

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are uploading the file separately. Therefore you will need two actions:

- `public string  Something(BugModel model)` for the model.
- `public string  FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)` for the file

Now, I would use [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) for ajax submitting. Here is an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#file-upload-form").submit(function () {
            $(this).ajaxSubmit({
                target: "#message",
                cache: false
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
@using(Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "LogABug", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "file-upload-form" })) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.File)
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </fieldset>
}
<div id="message">
</div>
```

What ever you return from your action will be displayed in the `div` with id `message`